# How to add array to Laravel db result row?

Tags: laravel

My code returns the first row from a Laravel `$data = DB::table('sometable')->select('id')->get();` using:

```
$row = $data->first();
```

I can then return id using:

```
$row->id;
```

How can I now add an array with key 'moredata' to that row collection object for referencing later in the code? I've tried:

```
$row->put('moredata', $moredata);
```

Where $moredata is a populated array and 'moredata' is not a field in the table. Laravel throws the error 'Call to undefined method stdClass::put()'. I could convert to an array and simply extend the array, just wondered if it could be done retaining the Laravel collection structure?

Comment: $row->moredata =  $moredata;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the property on the object directly.

```
$row = DB::table('sometable')->select('id')->first();
$row->moredata = $moredata;
```

Also, If you only need one record, use the `first` function on your query builder. Otherwise, you will query the database for all records and filter the first in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$appends = ['moredata']

function getMoredataAttribute() {
    return ['data' => '...data...'];
}
```

put this into your Model

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$data = DB::table('sometable')->select('id')->first();
$data->moredata = $moredata;
```

or

```
$data = DB::table('sometable')->select('id')->get();
$data = $data[0];
$data->moredata = $moredata;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append data: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

> Occasionally, when casting models to an array or JSON, you may wish to
>   add attributes that do not have a corresponding column in your
>   database.